# React: Returning a generic component from a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following absctraction:

```
function useSuspense<P extends Record<string, any>>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) {

  function Component(props: P) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={fallback}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  }

  return Component;
}
```

It is used like this:

```
const MyCompo = useMemo(() => lazy(() => import('paht-to-component'))), []);
```

The issue is to use this generic components:

```
type SomeTypeDefinition<T, R> = {
  typeValue?: T;
  returnValue?: R;
  someValue?: string;
};

export default function DummyComponent<T, R>(props: SomeTypeDefinition<T, R>) {
  return (
    <p>
      DummyComponent <b>{props.someValue}</b>
    </p>
  );
}
```

with my abstraction. The generic part: `<T, R>` gets lost. I can still use the props in `SomeTypeDefinition` while using `DummyComponent`.
This: `function Component(props: P)` allows me to have basic component typings. But not for generic types (I guess that is because `Component(props: P)` is not generic.). Any idea on how to customize this in such a way that I can use it like:
`<DummyComponent<TType, RType> />`, where `TType` and `RType` are some defined types would be welcome. For that, `useSuspense` has to be a `function` returning **a generic component**.
[See reproduction.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usesuspense-generic-vlhl6l?file=/src/App.tsx)